# Laravel hasOneThrough - Laravel relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I really need help with the following! I am trying to understand how `hasOneThrough` works

**Users table:**

id | belongs_to (id of the company)

**Companies Table:**

id | country_id

**Countries table:**

id

So I would like to know the country ID of a user through the Company... in **User** model I am trying the following:

```
public function country() {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            'App\Countries',
            'App\Companies',
            'country_id', // the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model...
            'id', // is the name of the foreign key on the final model...
            'belongs_to', // is the local key...
            'id' // is the local key of the intermediate model...
        );
    }
```

Also tried

```
public function country() {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            'App\Countries',
            'App\Companies',
            'country_id', // the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model...
            'belongs_to', // is the name of the foreign key on the final model...
            'id', // is the local key...
            'id' // is the local key of the intermediate model...
        );
    }
```

But always get `NULL` as result

Comment: This isn't an answer, however, I would suggest following Laravel's conventions if you can i.e. Model names should be singular versions of the table names (tables names should be plural) and `belongs_to` should be `company_id`. This way you won't need to specify extra data i.e. the table the model is related to and also the related keys in the relationships.

Comment: @rwd but I can not do that, the project is started already by someone else and I can not go back at this stage

Comment: `hasOneThrough` is really meant for getting a distant relationship through a `hasMany` relationship. For something like this you can simply do `$user->company->country`.

Comment: How do the table schemes of both the country and the company table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `hasOneThrough` isn't really meant to `belongsTo` relationships as you can get the model you're after by simply chaining the relationships together:

```
$user->company->country;
```

That being said, this should be the relationship that you want:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Countries::class, Companies::class, 'id', 'id', 'belongs_to', 'country_id'
    );
}
```

Comment: I understand your comment and is true I can access that way... then I think I need more study of the `hasOneThrough` ... the relationship is still not working but your answer make it simpler in my case, thanks